# How to change "transport" url in django celery config

Tags: django, docker-compose, redis, celery

I have django 3.2.7, celery 5.2.1, redis 3.5.3

I have next celery settings. (REDIS_PASSWORD) is env variable:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = f'redis://:{REDIS_PASSWORD}@redis:6379/4'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = f'redis://:{REDIS_PASSWORD}@redis:6379/1'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
```

But when I start my docker-compose app, it shows me

```
celery | --- ***** ----- 
celery | -- ******* ---- Linux-5.11.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2021-09-16 10:20:11
celery | - *** --- * --- 
celery | - ** ---------- [config]
celery | - ** ---------- .> app:         project:0x7f5cd0df0880
celery | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0 <==== NO CHANGES HERE
celery | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://:**@redis:6379/1
celery | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
celery | -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
celery | --- ***** -----
```

How can I set it?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by removing environment params from docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

CELERY_BROKER_URL and CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND have been changed to 'broker_url' and 'result_backend'respectively. When I changed to newer names for env variables, I was able to edit the transport url.

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved for me by removing `CELERY_BROKER` from `docker-compose` file.

when both of `CELERY_BROKER` and `CELERY_BROKER_URL` exists , celery gives priority to `CELERY_BROKER` variable.

and if it exists in `docker-compose` file , send to project as variable in settings.py